# Including IE8 specific css kills page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to make a couple of web pages work for a client in IE8, however I'm not getting anywhere at all.

I'm trying to include a css file to combat some of the issues, but whenever I include a stylesheet using:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-2.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

everything below the header of the page disappears. Even if there is nothing in the stylesheet at all!

Any ideas why this might be?

[Here's the page link](http://b9media.co.uk/tbw/basic-questions.html), if anyone wants it.

Comment: `charset=UTF-16`....that seems odd

Comment: I see the whole page.. Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: It works fine in my IE in 9 and 8